# Thymeleaf dropdowns not auto-populating upon clicking the edit button

Tags: java, html, twitter-bootstrap, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have an HTML page with thymeleaf template with a button called **"Create New"** and a  table multiple columns. At the end of each row, I have a button called **"edit"**.

**"Create new"** redirects to a page with a new form. The form has text fields and dropdowns and upon submitting, it creates a new row in the page with table.

The **"edit"** button should redirect to the same form page with all the fields auto-populated with the values of the row and upon submitting, it should update that particular row with the updated values.

The **"Create new"** button works perfectly but when I hit **"edit"** button, it rediewcts to the form with the text fields auto-populated with values of that row. But the dropdowns don't seem to be auto-populated. In fact, when I try to see the options of the dropdown, I see nothing.

If it helps, the dropdown values are taken from a HashMap.

Here's the snippet of my dropdown div that doesn't get auto-populated and the text box div that gets auto-populated -

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Dropdown Name:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <select class="custom-select form-control" th:field="*{XXX}">
            <option selected th:each="XXX : ${allXXX}" th:value="${XXX}" th:text="${XXX}">
                Choose XXX...
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-3">text name:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{Text}" placeholder="Enter the task alias" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Let me know if you need snippets of the controller class. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you adding the dropdown options to the model (`${allXXX}`) in both the edit and the create controllers?

Comment: Are you sure that you're adding/sending the **'options'** value for your edit page from your controller.?